# AWS Quicksight Convert week number and year to a date field

Tags: amazon-quicksight

Would Anyone know how to convert a week number and year to a date field.  Everything I have tried fails.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your 'week number' and 'year' data are integers with week 1 being equivalent to January 1st, see data sample below. Then the Quicksight calculated field formula is (for dayfirst date):

```
addDateTime((week_number*7)-7,'DD',parseDate(concat('01/01/',toString(year)), 'dd/MM/yyyy') )
```

You will have to adapt the formula for the relevant data types of your own columns. E.g. if your `week_number` and `year` columns were strings then the formula would be:

```
addDateTime((parseInt(week_number)*7)-7,'DD',parseDate(concat('01/01/',year), 'dd/MM/yyyy'))
```

Data sample with output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but when I use the formula I get an error- the syntax of the calculated field expression is incorrect

Comment: @Mike if you post your own actual data sample here or a screenshot of the Quicksight dataset editing UI then it would be easier to solve for you. I know the Quicksight error messages are next to useless in most cases. I have tested the two cases above (integer and string data types) and have confirmed they work in Quicksight as can be see from the screenshot I posted in the answer. Cheers.

Comment: good call, still very new to quicksight.  I replaced the week and year values with values from the dataset.  Both values are numeric. Here are the rows addDateTime((parseInt({Week}})*7)-7,'DD',parseDate(concat('01/01/',{RPT_YR}}), 'dd/MM/yyyy'))
/*addDateTime((parseInt(week_number)*7)-7,'DD',parseDate(concat('01/01/',year), 'dd/MM/yyyy'))*/